# Pydantic: is there a way to specify predefined validation behavior on a field of a Model?

Tags: python, pydantic

I would like the behavior of

```
class TestModel(BaseModel):
    field1: StrictStr  # we want to validate that this has length 5
    
    @validator('field1', always=True)
    def check_field1_length_5(cls, field1):
        if len(field1) != 5:
            raise ValueError(f'{field1=} does not have length 5')
        return field1
```

but writing something like

```
class TestModel(BaseModel):
    field1: Length5StrictStr
```

The point being that I want both of

- don't want to nest the field inside another Model
- don't want to write the validator each time I use that validation logic

Is this possible in pydantic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pydantic [`ConstrainedStr`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.7/pydantic/types.py#L399) (parent class of `StrictStr`) already provides a class attribute called `max_length` for this. So all you need to do is fix that in a custom subclass of `StrictStr`.

But if you want to add arbitrary constraints/validation logic, you can also override the [`validate`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.7/pydantic/types.py#L428) method.

Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictStr, ValidationError


class MaxLength5String(StrictStr):
    max_length = 5


class MustBeUpperString(StrictStr):
    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value: str) -> str:
        value = super().validate(value)
        if value.upper() != value:
            raise ValueError("Must be all upper-case")
        return value


class TestModel(BaseModel):
    foo: MaxLength5String
    bar: MustBeUpperString


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        TestModel(foo="abcdef", bar="Ab")
    except ValidationError as err:
        print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "foo"
        ],
        "msg": "ensure this value has at most 5 characters",
        "type": "value_error.any_str.max_length",
        "ctx": {
            "limit_value": 5
        }
    },
    {
        "loc": [
            "bar"
        ],
        "msg": "Must be all upper-case",
        "type": "value_error"
    }
]
```

See the [Custom Data Types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/#custom-data-types) section in the docs for more.